# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges triggering with error

Tags: ios, swift2, core-location

My application is triggering the method startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges but without executing any line of code (at least visible) it raises an error:

```
0x10f7daab3 <+35>:  callq  0x10f830250               ; function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded> of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)
->  0x10f7daab8 <+40>:  ud2 

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

I've placed breakpoint in almost all methods impacted by location manager, and also, in AppDelegate. None of them are hit.

Is there any way to trace it by taking those Hexa codes ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. It gaves me libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw:
->  0x110ef2c6b <+0>:   pushq  %rbp

Answer (score 0):

Those hexa codes are memory adress, you might debug by changing some values in memory but it requires some knowledge in assembly. Will be much easier to debug with the code imo, could you share it please?
(from what i see in your comment above, error comes from a bad argument send to a method, can't tell you more though)